# cakephp get query logs when debug is set to 0

Tags: php, logging, cakephp

How can you get a list of the executed queries when debug is set to 0 ?

I have the following functions in AppController:

```
// log INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE queries
private function __logQueries(){
    $db         = &ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
    $query_logs = $db->getLog();

    if( isset($query_logs['log']) && !empty($query_logs['log']) ){

        $this->loadModel('SqlLog');

        foreach($query_logs['log'] as $log_q){
            $query = $log_q['query'];
            if( stristr($query, 'INSERT ') || stristr($query, 'UPDATE ') || stristr($query, 'DELETE ') ){

                $q_data = array(
                        'query'     => $query,
                        'page'      => $this->Misc->getCurrentPageURL(),  // get the current page
                        'referrer'  => trim(env('HTTP_REFERER')) == '' ? '' : env('HTTP_REFERER'),
                        'ip'        => env('REMOTE_ADDR'),
                        'browser'   => env('HTTP_USER_AGENT'),
                        'user_id'   => SessionComponent::check('Auth.User') ? SessionComponent::read('Auth.User.id') : 0,
                        'username'  => SessionComponent::check('Auth.User') ? addslashes(SessionComponent::read('Auth.User.username')) : '',
                    );

                $this->SqlLog->create();
                $this->SqlLog->save($q_data);

            }
        }
    } // end if query occured

}

public function beforeRedirect(){
    $this->__logQueries();
}

public function afterFilter(){
    $this->__logQueries();
}
```

The insert, update and delete queries get logged when debug is set to 2, but how can I log those queries when debug is set to 0?

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether queries are being logged depends on the [**`DboSource::$fullDebug`**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-DboSource.html#%24fullDebug) property, it's being set in the `DboSource` constructur, and by default it's `true` in case `debug` is `> 1`.

So all you have to do is overwrite the value of this property with `true`, this will ensure that as of this point the queries are being logged regardless of the `debug` setting.

```
App::uses('ConnectionManager', 'Model');
ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default')->fullDebug = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

Create your own dbo file in the specified path:

```
\app\models\datasources\dbo\dbo_mysql_with_log.php
```

and the content of this file will be

```
<?php

class DboMysqlBase extends DboSource {
/**
 * Description property.
 *
 * @var string
 */
    var $description = "MySQL DBO Base Driver";
/**
 * Start quote
 *
 * @var string
 */
    var $startQuote = "`";
/**
 * End quote
 *
 * @var string
 */
    var $endQuote = "`";
/**
 * use alias for update and delete. Set to true if version >= 4.1
 *
 * @var boolean
 * @access protected
 */
    var $_useAlias = true;
/**
 * Index of basic SQL commands
 *
 * @var array
 * @access protected
 */
    var $_commands = array(
        'begin'    => 'START TRANSACTION',
        'commit'   => 'COMMIT',
        'rollback' => 'ROLLBACK'
    );
/**
 * MySQL column definition
 *
 * @var array
 */
    var $columns = array(
        'primary_key' => array('name' => 'NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT'),
        'string' => array('name' => 'varchar', 'limit' => '255'),
        'text' => array('name' => 'text'),
        'integer' => array('name' => 'int', 'limit' => '11', 'formatter' => 'intval'),
        'float' => array('name' => 'float', 'formatter' => 'floatval'),
        'datetime' => array('name' => 'datetime', 'format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s', 'formatter' => 'date'),
        'timestamp' => array('name' => 'timestamp', 'format' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s', 'formatter' => 'date'),
        'time' => array('name' => 'time', 'format' => 'H:i:s', 'formatter' => 'date'),
        'date' => array('name' => 'date', 'format' => 'Y-m-d', 'formatter' => 'date'),
        'binary' => array('name' => 'blob'),
        'boolean' => array('name' => 'tinyint', 'limit' => '1')
    );
/**
 * Generates and executes an SQL UPDATE statement for given model, fields, and values.
 *
 * @param Model $model
 * @param array $fields
 * @param array $values
 * @param mixed $conditions
 * @return array
 */
    function update(&$model, $fields = array(), $values = null, $conditions = null) {
        if (!$this->_useAlias) {
            return parent::update($model, $fields, $values, $conditions);
        }

        if ($values == null) {
            $combined = $fields;
        } else {
            $combined = array_combine($fields, $values);
        }

        $alias = $joins = false;
        $fields = $this->_prepareUpdateFields($model, $combined, empty($conditions), !empty($conditions));
        $fields = join(', ', $fields);
        $table = $this->fullTableName($model);

        if (!empty($conditions)) {
            $alias = $this->name($model->alias);
            if ($model->name == $model->alias) {
                $joins = implode(' ', $this->_getJoins($model));
            }
        }
        $conditions = $this->conditions($this->defaultConditions($model, $conditions, $alias), true, true, $model);

        if ($conditions === false) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!$this->execute($this->renderStatement('update', compact('table', 'alias', 'joins', 'fields', 'conditions')))) {
            $model->onError();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
/**
 * Generates and executes an SQL DELETE statement for given id/conditions on given model.
 *
 * @param Model $model
 * @param mixed $conditions
 * @return boolean Success
 */
    function delete(&$model, $conditions = null) {
        if (!$this->_useAlias) {
            return parent::delete($model, $conditions);
        }
        $alias = $this->name($model->alias);
        $table = $this->fullTableName($model);
        $joins = implode(' ', $this->_getJoins($model));

        if (empty($conditions)) {
            $alias = $joins = false;
        }
        $conditions = $this->conditions($this->defaultConditions($model, $conditions, $alias), true, true, $model);

        if ($conditions === false) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($this->execute($this->renderStatement('delete', compact('alias', 'table', 'joins', 'conditions'))) === false) {
            $model->onError();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
/**
 * Sets the database encoding
 *
 * @param string $enc Database encoding
 */
    function setEncoding($enc) {
        return $this->_execute('SET NAMES ' . $enc) != false;
    }
/**
 * Returns an array of the indexes in given datasource name.
 *
 * @param string $model Name of model to inspect
 * @return array Fields in table. Keys are column and unique
 */
    function index($model) {
        $index = array();
        $table = $this->fullTableName($model);
        if ($table) {
            $indexes = $this->query('SHOW INDEX FROM ' . $table);
            if (isset($indexes[0]['STATISTICS'])) {
                $keys = Set::extract($indexes, '{n}.STATISTICS');
            } else {
                $keys = Set::extract($indexes, '{n}.0');
            }
            foreach ($keys as $i => $key) {
                if (!isset($index[$key['Key_name']])) {
                    $col = array();
                    $index[$key['Key_name']]['column'] = $key['Column_name'];
                    $index[$key['Key_name']]['unique'] = intval($key['Non_unique'] == 0);
                } else {
                    if (!is_array($index[$key['Key_name']]['column'])) {
                        $col[] = $index[$key['Key_name']]['column'];
                    }
                    $col[] = $key['Column_name'];
                    $index[$key['Key_name']]['column'] = $col;
                }
            }
        }
        return $index;
    }
/**
 * Generate a MySQL Alter Table syntax for the given Schema comparison
 *
 * @param array $compare Result of a CakeSchema::compare()
 * @return array Array of alter statements to make.
 */
    function alterSchema($compare, $table = null) {
        if (!is_array($compare)) {
            return false;
        }
        $out = '';
        $colList = array();
        foreach ($compare as $curTable => $types) {
            $indexes = array();
            if (!$table || $table == $curTable) {
                $out .= 'ALTER TABLE ' . $this->fullTableName($curTable) . " \n";
                foreach ($types as $type => $column) {
                    if (isset($column['indexes'])) {
                        $indexes[$type] = $column['indexes'];
                        unset($column['indexes']);
                    }
                    switch ($type) {
                        case 'add':
                            foreach ($column as $field => $col) {
                                $col['name'] = $field;
                                $alter = 'ADD '.$this->buildColumn($col);
                                if (isset($col['after'])) {
                                    $alter .= ' AFTER '. $this->name($col['after']);
                                }
                                $colList[] = $alter;
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'drop':
                            foreach ($column as $field => $col) {
                                $col['name'] = $field;
                                $colList[] = 'DROP '.$this->name($field);
                            }
                        break;
                        case 'change':
                            foreach ($column as $field => $col) {
                                if (!isset($col['name'])) {
                                    $col['name'] = $field;
                                }
                                $colList[] = 'CHANGE '. $this->name($field).' '.$this->buildColumn($col);
                            }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                $colList = array_merge($colList, $this->_alterIndexes($curTable, $indexes));
                $out .= "\t" . join(",\n\t", $colList) . ";\n\n";
            }
        }
        return $out;
    }
/**
 * Generate a MySQL "drop table" statement for the given Schema object
 *
 * @param object $schema An instance of a subclass of CakeSchema
 * @param string $table Optional.  If specified only the table name given will be generated.
 *                      Otherwise, all tables defined in the schema are generated.
 * @return string
 */
    function dropSchema($schema, $table = null) {
        if (!is_a($schema, 'CakeSchema')) {
            trigger_error(__('Invalid schema object', true), E_USER_WARNING);
            return null;
        }
        $out = '';
        foreach ($schema->tables as $curTable => $columns) {
            if (!$table || $table == $curTable) {
                $out .= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' . $this->fullTableName($curTable) . ";\n";
            }
        }
        return $out;
    }
/**
 * Generate MySQL index alteration statements for a table.
 *
 * @param string $table Table to alter indexes for
 * @param array $new Indexes to add and drop
 * @return array Index alteration statements
 */
    function _alterIndexes($table, $indexes) {
        $alter = array();
        if (isset($indexes['drop'])) {
            foreach($indexes['drop'] as $name => $value) {
                $out = 'DROP ';
                if ($name == 'PRIMARY') {
                    $out .= 'PRIMARY KEY';
                } else {
                    $out .= 'KEY ' . $name;
                }
                $alter[] = $out;
            }
        }
        if (isset($indexes['add'])) {
            foreach ($indexes['add'] as $name => $value) {
                $out = 'ADD ';
                if ($name == 'PRIMARY') {
                    $out .= 'PRIMARY ';
                    $name = null;
                } else {
                    if (!empty($value['unique'])) {
                        $out .= 'UNIQUE ';
                    }
                }
                if (is_array($value['column'])) {
                    $out .= 'KEY '. $name .' (' . join(', ', array_map(array(&$this, 'name'), $value['column'])) . ')';
                } else {
                    $out .= 'KEY '. $name .' (' . $this->name($value['column']) . ')';
                }
                $alter[] = $out;
            }
        }
        return $alter;
    }
/**
 * Inserts multiple values into a table
 *
 * @param string $table
 * @param string $fields
 * @param array $values
 */
    function insertMulti($table, $fields, $values) {
        $table = $this->fullTableName($table);
        if (is_array($fields)) {
            $fields = join(', ', array_map(array(&$this, 'name'), $fields));
        }
        $values = implode(', ', $values);
        $this->query("INSERT INTO {$table} ({$fields}) VALUES {$values}");
    }
}
class DboMysql extends DboMysqlBase {
/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @var unknown_type
 */
    var $description = "MySQL DBO Driver";
/**
 * Base configuration settings for MySQL driver
 *
 * @var array
 */
    var $_baseConfig = array(
        'persistent' => true,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'cake',
        'port' => '3306',
        'connect' => 'mysql_pconnect'
    );
/**
 * Connects to the database using options in the given configuration array.
 *
 * @return boolean True if the database could be connected, else false
 */
    function connect() {
        $config = $this->config;
        $connect = $config['connect'];
        $this->connected = false;

        if (!$config['persistent']) {
            $this->connection = mysql_connect($config['host'] . ':' . $config['port'], $config['login'], $config['password'], true);
        } else {
            $this->connection = $connect($config['host'] . ':' . $config['port'], $config['login'], $config['password']);
        }

        if (mysql_select_db($config['database'], $this->connection)) {
            $this->connected = true;
        }

        if (isset($config['encoding']) && !empty($config['encoding'])) {
            $this->setEncoding($config['encoding']);
        }

        $this->_useAlias = (bool)version_compare(mysql_get_server_info($this->connection), "4.1", ">=");

        return $this->connected;
    }
/**
 * Disconnects from database.
 *
 * @return boolean True if the database could be disconnected, else false
 */
    function disconnect() {
        if (isset($this->results) && is_resource($this->results)) {
            mysql_free_result($this->results);
        }
        $this->connected = !@mysql_close($this->connection);
        return !$this->connected;
    }
/**
 * Executes given SQL statement.
 *
 * @param string $sql SQL statement
 * @return resource Result resource identifier
 * @access protected
 */
    function _execute($sql) {
        return mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
    }
/**
 * Returns an array of sources (tables) in the database.
 *
 * @return array Array of tablenames in the database
 */
    function listSources() {
        $cache = parent::listSources();
        if ($cache != null) {
            return $cache;
        }
        $result = $this->_execute('SHOW TABLES FROM ' . $this->name($this->config['database']) . ';');

        if (!$result) {
            return array();
        } else {
            $tables = array();

            while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                $tables[] = $line[0];
            }
            parent::listSources($tables);
            return $tables;
        }
    }
/**
 * Returns an array of the fields in given table name.
 *
 * @param string $tableName Name of database table to inspect
 * @return array Fields in table. Keys are name and type
 */
    function describe(&$model) {
        $cache = parent::describe($model);
        if ($cache != null) {
            return $cache;
        }
        $fields = false;
        $cols = $this->query('DESCRIBE ' . $this->fullTableName($model));

        foreach ($cols as $column) {
            $colKey = array_keys($column);
            if (isset($column[$colKey[0]]) && !isset($column[0])) {
                $column[0] = $column[$colKey[0]];
            }
            if (isset($column[0])) {
                $fields[$column[0]['Field']] = array(
                    'type'      => $this->column($column[0]['Type']),
                    'null'      => ($column[0]['Null'] == 'YES' ? true : false),
                    'default'   => $column[0]['Default'],
                    'length'    => $this->length($column[0]['Type']),
                );
                if (!empty($column[0]['Key']) && isset($this->index[$column[0]['Key']])) {
                    $fields[$column[0]['Field']]['key'] = $this->index[$column[0]['Key']];
                }
            }
        }
        $this->__cacheDescription($this->fullTableName($model, false), $fields);
        return $fields;
    }
/**
 * Returns a quoted and escaped string of $data for use in an SQL statement.
 *
 * @param string $data String to be prepared for use in an SQL statement
 * @param string $column The column into which this data will be inserted
 * @param boolean $safe Whether or not numeric data should be handled automagically if no column data is provided
 * @return string Quoted and escaped data
 */
    function value($data, $column = null, $safe = false) {
        $parent = parent::value($data, $column, $safe);

        if ($parent != null) {
            return $parent;
        }
        if ($data === null || (is_array($data) && empty($data))) {
            return 'NULL';
        }
        if ($data === '' && $column !== 'integer' && $column !== 'float' && $column !== 'boolean') {
            return  "''";
        }
        if (empty($column)) {
            $column = $this->introspectType($data);
        }

        switch ($column) {
            case 'boolean':
                return $this->boolean((bool)$data);
            break;
            case 'integer':
            case 'float':
                if ($data === '') {
                    return 'NULL';
                }
                if ((is_int($data) || is_float($data) || $data === '0') || (
                    is_numeric($data) && strpos($data, ',') === false &&
                    $data[0] != '0' && strpos($data, 'e') === false)) {
                        return $data;
                    }
            default:
                $data = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($data, $this->connection) . "'";
            break;
        }
        return $data;
    }
/**
 * Returns a formatted error message from previous database operation.
 *
 * @return string Error message with error number
 */
    function lastError() {
        if (mysql_errno($this->connection)) {
            return mysql_errno($this->connection).': '.mysql_error($this->connection);
        }
        return null;
    }
/**
 * Returns number of affected rows in previous database operation. If no previous operation exists,
 * this returns false.
 *
 * @return integer Number of affected rows
 */
    function lastAffected() {
        if ($this->_result) {
            return mysql_affected_rows($this->connection);
        }
        return null;
    }
/**
 * Returns number of rows in previous resultset. If no previous resultset exists,
 * this returns false.
 *
 * @return integer Number of rows in resultset
 */
    function lastNumRows() {
        if ($this->hasResult()) {
            return mysql_num_rows($this->_result);
        }
        return null;
    }
/**
 * Returns the ID generated from the previous INSERT operation.
 *
 * @param unknown_type $source
 * @return in
 */
    function lastInsertId($source = null) {
        $id = $this->fetchRow('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS insertID', false);
        if ($id !== false && !empty($id) && !empty($id[0]) && isset($id[0]['insertID'])) {
            return $id[0]['insertID'];
        }

        return null;
    }
/**
 * Converts database-layer column types to basic types
 *
 * @param string $real Real database-layer column type (i.e. "varchar(255)")
 * @return string Abstract column type (i.e. "string")
 */
    function column($real) {
        if (is_array($real)) {
            $col = $real['name'];
            if (isset($real['limit'])) {
                $col .= '('.$real['limit'].')';
            }
            return $col;
        }

        $col = str_replace(')', '', $real);
        $limit = $this->length($real);
        if (strpos($col, '(') !== false) {
            list($col, $vals) = explode('(', $col);
        }

        if (in_array($col, array('date', 'time', 'datetime', 'timestamp'))) {
            return $col;
        }
        if (($col == 'tinyint' && $limit == 1) || $col == 'boolean') {
            return 'boolean';
        }
        if (strpos($col, 'int') !== false) {
            return 'integer';
        }
        if (strpos($col, 'char') !== false || $col == 'tinytext') {
            return 'string';
        }
        if (strpos($col, 'text') !== false) {
            return 'text';
        }
        if (strpos($col, 'blob') !== false || $col == 'binary') {
            return 'binary';
        }
        if (strpos($col, 'float') !== false || strpos($col, 'double') !== false || strpos($col, 'decimal') !== false) {
            return 'float';
        }
        if (strpos($col, 'enum') !== false) {
            return "enum($vals)";
        }
        return 'text';
    }
/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @param unknown_type $results
 */
    function resultSet(&$results) {
        if (isset($this->results) && is_resource($this->results) && $this->results != $results) {
            mysql_free_result($this->results);
        }
        $this->results =& $results;
        $this->map = array();
        $numFields = mysql_num_fields($results);
        $index = 0;
        $j = 0;

        while ($j < $numFields) {

            $column = mysql_fetch_field($results,$j);
            if (!empty($column->table)) {
                $this->map[$index++] = array($column->table, $column->name);
            } else {
                $this->map[$index++] = array(0, $column->name);
            }
            $j++;
        }
    }
/**
 * Fetches the next row from the current result set
 *
 * @return unknown
 */
    function fetchResult() {
        if ($row = mysql_fetch_row($this->results)) {
            $resultRow = array();
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($row as $index => $field) {
                list($table, $column) = $this->map[$index];
                $resultRow[$table][$column] = $row[$index];
                $i++;
            }
            return $resultRow;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
/**
 * Gets the database encoding
 *
 * @return string The database encoding
 */
    function getEncoding() {
        return mysql_client_encoding($this->connection);
    }
}
class DboMysqlWithLog extends DboMysql {
function _execute($sql) {  
        //exclude these types of queries from being logged, change if required
        if(!preg_match('/^SHOW|SELECT|DESCRIBE|cake_sessions.*/',$sql) && !preg_match('/^SET.*/',$sql)){

            //HH_DOCUMENT_ROOT should be defined in one of the core files pointing to the project root directory, if its not there define it
            //do not commit changes, if its specific to local machine
            //$filename = HH_DOCUMENT_ROOT.DS.'sql.txt';
            $filename = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\your_project_dir\app\sql.txt';
            $patfile = fopen($filename, 'a+');
              $textdata = "$sql\n";
              fwrite($patfile, $textdata);

              fclose($patfile);
        } 

        return parent::_execute($sql);
  }
}

?>
```

change sql log file path  $filename = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\your_project_dir\app\sql.txt';

Step 2: Open `/app/config/database.php`
and change  `'driver' => 'dbo_mysql_with_log',`

This will record all your sql scripts in the below path

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\your_project_dir\app\sql.txt
```

Comment: I tried something similar to your suggestion. I modified the _execute() function from DboSource by saving the query in a mysql table. It worked, but when i tried to get the lastInserteID, (for example the last id when a user is saved),it returned the last id of the log_queries